# Where are the droid legs on M4-78 in The Sith Lords Restored Content Mod?

Tags: mods, star-wars-kotor-2

I've recently reinstalled KOTOR II with the Restored Content Mod and have gotten to the Droid Planet (M4-78). I've been okay with the other quests, but Fixing Droids quest has me stumped. I've repaired both the droid in environmental and the droid outside the industrial sector, but I cannot find the legs that the droid by the landing pad entrance needs. Any one know where I should look?

Alternatively if anyone has found a guide/walkthrough for that includes the sections added by the Restored content mod that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I know you buy the legs from the Black Market Droid, though it will cost you quite a lot of credits. If you want to get some Dark Side points, talk to one of the huge droids will more than two legs, and you'll have the option of destroying it to get the legs.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy the legs, after visiting M4-78, from the Black Market Droid.

However M4-78 forbids this droid from talking to people. You will have to destroy Mover in the Central Area and get the Points of the Dark Side first.